# Binary Tree in Python Count nodes in range

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

I have a simple implementation of Binary Tree:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item, left = None, right = None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self, item):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(item, None, None)
        else:
            child_tree = self.root
            while child_tree != None:
                parent = child_tree
                if item < child_tree.item:
                    child_tree = child_tree.left
                else:
                    child_tree = child_tree.right
            if item < parent.item:
                parent.left = Node(item, None, None)
            elif item > parent.item:
                parent.right = Node(item, None, None)
```

I want to add count(lo,hi) method which counts all nodes in range(lo,hi) (including hi) This is what i have so far:

```
def count(self, lo, hi, ptr='lol', count=0):
    if ptr == 'lol':
        ptr = self.root
    if ptr.left != None:
        if ptr.item >= lo and ptr.item <= hi:
            count += 1
        ptr.left = self.count(lo, hi, ptr.left, count)
    if ptr.right != None:
        if ptr.item >= lo and ptr.item <= hi:
            count += 1
        ptr.right = self.count(lo, hi, ptr.right, count)
    return count
```

It only seems to work when the binary tree is right leaning or left leaning. It doesn't work for balanced trees and I have no idea why. My input is:

```
bst = BST()
for ele in [10, 150, 80, 40, 20, 10, 30, 60, 50, 70, 120, 100, 90, 110, 140, 130, 150]:
    bst.add(ele)
print(bst.count(30, 100))
```

My code gives me `output: 0` but it should say `output: 8`. Can you tell me where I went wrong please?

Comment: Shouldn't it "say": `output 8`?

Comment: @CristiFati Oh yeah sorry, will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that is wrong:

```
   while child_tree != None:
        if child_tree.item >= lo and child_tree.item <= hi:
            count += 1
        if hi > child_tree.item:  # from here
            child_tree = child_tree.right
        else:
            child_tree = child_tree.left . # to here
```

if `child_tree` is between low and hi you should iterate **both** left and right childs recursively - and you're iterating only the right child.

Hint: since you need to check both right and left childs there should be a recursive call...

**UPDATE**

```
def count(self, lo, hi, ptr, count=0):
    if not ptr:
        return 0
    elif lo <= ptr.item <= hi:
        return 1 + self.count(lo, hi, ptr.left, count) + \
               self.count(lo, hi, ptr.right, count)
    elif ptr.item < lo:
        return self.count(lo, hi, ptr.right, count)
    elif ptr.item > hi:
        return self.count(lo, hi, ptr.left, count)
```

Comment: I am trying the recursion but whenever i say self.root.right.count() it gives me an error, any idea why?

Comment: I would guess that either `self.root.right` is `None` or that `count` is implemented in class BST (not in class Node)

Comment: I finally made recursion in my method and updated my question, but it returns 0 for some reason, do you know why ?

Comment: `ptr.left = self.count(lo, hi, ptr.left, count)` the call to `count` should return a number - not a pointer to a node (same applies to the other call)

Comment: You're not handling all the cases: what if `ptr.item < lo` or `ptr.item > hi` ?

Comment: I am sorry I give up. Can you please show me how? I spent 2+ hrs on this and I feel like my head is going to blow up

Comment: I only want to count all nodes in range 30 to 100 inclusive therefore if it is higher or lower i dont add 1 to count

Comment: I updated the answer, play with this solution, then delete it and try to re-write a solution of your own (don't try to memorize it - try to understand how it's doing what it does). Do that, and you'll learn!

Comment: How in the hell, honestly. So the first elif statement is where the magic is happening

Comment: some of it, not *all* of it :) I personally am a big fan of the first `if`: it saves you all the `None` checks when you're calling with node.left and node.right

Comment: Ok so if the tree is empty or reaches a parent with no child it returns 0. if lo is bigger than a node it goes right and if hi is less it goes left. If node is within lo and hi, it returns 1 and repeats the process?

Comment: Well, I'll try to implement a method which measures a height of a binary tree